# IQ test to screen coordinates in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an IQ test result which ranges from 40 to 180 and that scale shows up on screen 50 pixels from the bottom and 50 pixels from the top.

In silverlight I position the first keyframe of the textbox i want to move 50 pixels from the bottom and programmatically set the end keyframe to where i want it animated to programmatically.

I am pretty much stumped with the scaling formula as to how to where to tell the object to move on the screen.

I would also like to reverse the formula to place the IQ value inside the textbox using the y position as I want value to follow the position based on easing.

```
        marginBottom = ResultText.Margin.Bottom; // the start position of the textBlock
        marginTop = EndPosition.To.Value; // the position i want it animating to

        EndPosition.To = ((iq/(180-40))*(marginTop-marginBottom)); // where to move it relating to iq

        AnimateUp.Begin(); // This is the storyboard
```

and then in the CompositionTarget_Rendering handler I'm looking to reverse the formula to show the iq value in the textblock that is animating.

Comment: max 180? That won't be enough, for say, Jon Skeet!

Comment: the range could be from 0 to 200 it doesn't have to be particularly for IQs but 40-180 should equate to 50px from bottom to 50px from the top.

Comment: @Joseph Le Brech: Can you provide a sample of your Xaml or screenshots or a clearer example of the animation you want to perform?

Comment: what I am trying to do is code related, I have the animation working. but i'm modifying the endpoint's position so that it scales.

Comment: i've edited my post with the code i have used up to now.

Comment: Whats the scale? is high IQ on the marginTop or marginBottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming IQ 40 should be at marginBottom and IQ 180 should be at marginTop

the formula would be

```
EndPosition.To = ( (marginTop - marginBottom)*iq + 180*marginBottom - 40*marginTop )/140;
```

Not having the full code its hard to tell, but you might have a bug in that you're determining marginTop from "EndPosition.To.Value", but you change "EndPosition.To" for the animation.

If you don't set "EndPosition.To" back to its original value, marginTop will never be the same thing twice.  Just something to watch out for.

Comment: this does not work, as it goes downwards. top, left is 0,0 so it's going downwards.

Comment: the Endposition is -545 and the margin bottom is 103. I think i'm mixing two different kinds of coordinates here which is my issue

Comment: @Joseph Le Brech - Fixed a bug.  The formula I gave will be equal to marginBottom when iq = 40, and equal to marginTop when iq = 180.  But yes, you need to check how you're determining marginTop and marginBottom